# Python list slicing range

Tags: python

I am a new Python learner. I was stopped by some codes like below:

```
return ['FizzBuzz'[i%-3&-4:i%-5&8^12]or`i`for i in range(1,n+1)]
```

Especially what does it mean: `[i%-3&-4:i%-5&8^12]`

Thank you so much!

Comment: where are you encountering code like this if you are new to python?

Comment: Such code shouldn't be used in real world programs. It won't help you to understand Python better (which is intended to be simple and clear) but only to understand the weird definition of "fun" some programmers have ;)  See also https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @0TTT0. [LeetCode](https://github.com/kamyu104/LeetCode/blob/master/Python/fizz-buzz.py).

Comment: `&` and `^` are bitwise operators.  `i%-3&-4` goes `0, -4, -4` repeating, while `i%-5&8^12` goes `12, 4, 4, 4, 4` repeating.  Note how the starting slice index repeats its pattern every three, while the ending index repeats every five.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` is the range symbol, meaning give me the list elements between start and end in `list[start:end]`.

`%` is the modulo operator, 
`&` is the binary (bit-wise) and operator, so the first part:

`i%-3&-4`

is equal to `mod(i, -3) & -4`

`^` is the exclusive or operator, so the second part:

`i%-5&8^12`

is equal to `mod(i, -5 ) & 8^12`

The modulo operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second.

If you need to know more about python binary (bit-wise) operators [look here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

As stated in the comments, without the back-tics `` , the last part after the or statement returns a range from `1 to n+1`, if the resulting fist list is empty.

The back ticks, in that statement is Python2 syntax for the repr() function.
See [repr documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)  for more info

Comment: and the `or` part with backticks?

Comment: @PeterWood I don't understand the backticks, but without them if the string slice is empty then the value of `i` is used

Comment: @PatrickHaugh. Backticks are a deprecated way to spell `repr(i)` - so the code in the question is python2.

Comment: The operator precedence is all wrong up there. `i%-3&-4` is only sometimes equal to `i%(-3&-4)`

Comment: I think you misunderstood the comment by Patrick Haugh. He did not mean to imply that a range would be returned if the `\`i\`` wasn't there (that would be a syntax error). All he meant was that the value of `i` would be used if the string slice is empty.